# How to avoid circular dependencies between Android modules?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, multi-module

I am currently working on a multi-module app. The main module (app) handles authentication screens, the datasource module handles all networking/database queries (for now I am using a single module, but I am taking into consideration to split it), followed by some feature modules which can be used based on the user privileges.

I retrieve a token after login which I am planning to keep inside SharedPreferences, but I would like to put it inside an Interceptor for my Retrofit client in my datasource module in order to avoid passing it as params for every call.

I was thinking to include the dagger module which provides the application context inside my datasource graph, but that would add a circular dependency between app and datasource.

I am using a singleton object that I inject inside the app module in order to retrieve data from the datasource.

As I will also need to create the database besides SharedPreferences access, I will need to retrieve context inside my datasource module. What is the best way to do this, in order to avoid circular dependencies?